# how to extract just domain name from URL in notepad++ with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I extract just domain name from a list of url in notepad++?

Examples:

```
https://www.example.com/aa  ---> example.com
https://example.com/aa  ---> example.com
http://www.example.com/aa  ---> example.com
http://example.com/aa  ---> example.com
www.example.com/aa  ---> example.com
example.com/aa  ---> example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`https?` - match `http` and `s` if there is one (due to `?` operator)

`:\/\/` - match `://` literally

`?:https?:\/\/)?` - match pattern (`https?:\/\/)` zero or more times

`(?:www\.)?` - match `www.` literally, zero or one time

`([^\/]+)` - match one or more characters other than `/` and store it in first capturing group, this will be text you want to match

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCPHOD/1)